# How can we Update Specified part of string in query dynamically

Tags: sql-server

For example I got following text

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8"><link href="Heights.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
```

I need to Update "Heights.css`" to "`C:\Temp\Heights.css`" .

The name of the CSS file will be Changing from record to record.

I'm not sure line at which it starts. Please help me on this

Comment: Edited question , my bad as it was not put correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
update tableName
set ColumnName = REPLACE(ColumnName,'Heights.css','C:\Temp\Heights.css')
```

You can easily update using replace routine.
In your case you need to identify which css file name needs to be replaced with which file name.

Comment: The name of the css file will be changing from record to record

Comment: I think you need to elaborate your requirement or need to apply your own logic to identify the file name which needs to be updated against current file name.